# Are UK civil partnerships still 'monogamous'?

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage

With civil partnerships soon opening to everyone in the UK, I have been unabe to find whether - like with marriage - you are limited to have one with only a single person?
Could some insight with sources be provided on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Section 1 paragraph 1 of the Civil Partnership Act 2004 says:

> A civil partnership is a relationship between **two** people of the same sex

[My emphasis]

To show that you can't form multiple civil partnerships, Section 3 says:

> Eligibility
>
> (1)Two people are not eligible to register as civil partners of each other if—
>
> (a)they are not of the same sex,
>
> **(b)either of them is already a civil partner or lawfully married,**
>
> (c)either of them is under 16, or
>
> (d)they are within prohibited degrees of relationship.
>
> (2)Part 1 of Schedule 1 contains provisions for determining when two people are within prohibited degrees of relationship.

See: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/33/section/1

The recently announced change to allow heterosexual couples to register a civil partnership will presumably just involve deleting "of the same sex" from 1.1 and deleting 3.1(a)

Formalizing polyamorous relationships is quite a way off I think (and will be quite a lot more complex).

Comment: This part of the law does not explicitly forbid one from being partof multiple partnerships, though; just that any one partnership is between two people.

Comment: @WeckarE. - fair point.  I've added a bit more.  3.1(b) is pretty explicit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess we won't be taking the plunge, then.

Comment: @WeckarE. If you are actually *in* a polyamorous relationship, I *very* strongly suggest you need wills, and wills drawn up by a lawyer (but you need to discuss first what you want the wills to say).  If any of you have a defined-benefits pension which offers a widow(er)s pension, it might be worth them marrying the person most likely to survive longest in order to take advantage of it.  Obviously everyone's names should be on the deeds/tenancy.

Comment: Unfortunately the relationship is a web, not a bubble. Not everyone is involved with everyone, so to speak. Thanks for the advice, anyway. Luckily we do not all live together either.

Comment: @WeckarE. - you still need wills!